# Вычислить значение на python. Вообще не понял что делать, новичок, объясните принцип и этапы решения

Tags: python-3.x, математика

понял только что нужен math.log10, но не уверен.в интернете нет примеров похожих задач, от которых я бы мог оттолкнуться.
[image: задание]

Answer (score 2):

В первой строке прописываем `import math` для импортирования модуля `math`

```
def func(x, y):
    return math.log10((math.sin(x ** 2)) / (abs(math.cos(y)) + 2))
```

- Ключевое слово `def` определяет функцию с названием `func`, как мы
  указали далее
- В скобках записываются аргументы функции, в данном случае - `(x, y)`, то есть функция по порядку принимает два числа: `x` и `y`
- Ключевое слово `return` говорит о том, что при вызове функции следующая конструкция с подстановкой чисел вернёт выходное число
- `math.log10(a)` вернёт десятичный логарифм числа `a`, но мы вычисляем прямо внутри скобок
- Дробь мы представим в виде знака деления: `(math.sin(x**2))` - числитель,
  `(abs(math.cos(y)) + 2)` - знаменатель.
- Обозначением возведения в степень в Python является двойная звёздочка `**`

`math.sin(x ** 2)` возвращает синус x в квадрате в радианах
`abs(math.cos(y)) + 2` возвращает модуль косинуса от y в радианах + 2

- Конструкция `(math.sin(x ** 2)) / (abs(math.cos(y)) + 2)` вернёт дробь, приведённую в вопросе
- И в конце `math.log10()` подсчитывает десятичный логарифм дроби и `return` возвращает число

В итоге в коде нужно просто вызвать функцию `func` с параметрами `x` и `y`, например:

```
func(1, 2)
```

Код:

```
import math

def func(x, y):
    return math.log10((math.sin(x ** 2)) / (abs(math.cos(y)) + 2))
```

Если необходимы синус и косинус в градусах, то нужно использовать такой код:

```
import math

def log10asker(x, y):
    return math.log10(math.sin(math.radians(x) ** 2) / (abs(math.cos(math.radians(y))) + 2))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! ознакомлюсь, если что-то не понятно - спрошу